# How can I print out a 1000 by 1000 grid of points without excessive runtime?

Tags: java

```
int[][] graph = new int[1000][1000];

for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(new Point(i, j));
    }

    System.out.println();
}

public class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
```

I can get the code to print out a 1000 by 1000 grid of points, but I would like to have the program print out the grid without excessive runtime.

Comment: Have you tried building a single `String` containing the output you want and then just printing that?

Comment: Define "excessive runtime". What is your baseline and how did you come up with that. What makes you think it can be improved from what you have right now?

Comment: It took about 16 seconds to print out the entire grid.

Comment: Can we also see the code for your `Point` class?

Comment: 16 seconds to print a million points is 16 microseconds per point.  That does not seem slow to me, especially given that I/O is one of the slowest things you can ask a computer to do.

Comment: My computer can run that code in 3 seconds.

Comment: For me, using `java.awt.Point`, piping output to a file to eliminate output drawing/scrolling delays, it took **6 seconds** to write 26,782,000 bytes. Doing what [@JacobG. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926257/how-can-i-print-out-a-1000-by-1000-grid-of-points-without-excessive-runtime#comment98506133_55926257), it ran in **0.4 seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

As [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926257/how-can-i-print-out-a-1000-by-1000-grid-of-points-without-excessive-runtime#comment98506317_55926257) stated in the comments above, "I/O is one of the slowest things you can ask a computer to do."

Because your goal is to print a grid to the console, I recommend building a `String` that contains the grid, and then print it (rather than printing each element of it sequentially).

Your updated code would look something like the following:

```
int[][] graph = new int[1_000][1_000];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1_000_000);

for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++) {
        sb.append(new Point(i, j));
    }

    sb.append('\n');
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Without properly benchmarking this, it's still completing in less than 400ms on average, whereas your old code completed for me in a little under 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is also a other problem in the code: 
In the second for-loop you are accesing the length of the first column of graph. That will cause that if your using this code with a diffrent size of columns and rows, that the output would be still have the same size of rows and columns. This could be fixed by accessing `graph[i].length` in the second for-loop.